# Picking first instance in grouped rows- PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Here's the background, I have a set of rows:

[image]

I only want to get the first ADVANCE after every RECOVERY in the type column per accountid

so I the result should be the advances with procdates

```
2015-09-03 09:55:12.228343
2015-09-04 23:10:42.016903
```

Is this possible in one query?

Comment: Please don't post sample data as screenshots. Post it as formatted text - or even better: as SQL insert scripts. Check this for more information on your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have found on how to get it!

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT accountid,
    procdate, 
        type, 
        value, 
        LAG(type) OVER (ORDER BY procdate ASC) AS previousType
   FROM transaction) w WHERE previousType = 'RECOVERY';
```

Comment: 1) Your query is restricted for only one accountid
2) It will return 3 rows instead of 2 rows as mentioned in quetion. It will be returning following rows:
2015-09-03 09:55:12.228343 (row 2)
2013-09-03 23:14:53 (row 14)
2015-09-04 23:10:42.016903 (row 15)

In your query you are only considering previousType = 'RECOVERY'
As type column has 3 rows where type = 'RECOVERY'. Your query will return 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE_PrevType
AS (
    SELECT accountid
        ,procdate
        ,LAG(type, 1, NULL) OVER (
            ORDER BY procdate
            ) AS PreviousType
    FROM < Table_Name >
    )
SELECT
accountid
,procdate
,type
,value
FROM < Table_Name > AS TN
INNER JOIN CTE_PrevType CPT
    ON TN.accountid = CPT.accountid
        AND TN.procdate = CPT.procdate
WHERE TN.type = 'ADVANCE'
    AND CPT.type = 'RECOVERY'
```

Comment: Actually This did not work but It gave me and Idea about LAG! thanks!

Comment: Note: `CPT.PreviousType = 'RECOVERY'` And you are missing a `PARTITION BY orderid` in the window.